# Show Keyboard always in a certain condition in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, keyboard

I've creating a custom control that contains an entry and some labels and buttons. (it is basically a animated entry with place holder).

In my control, there is an Eye button for IsPassword property. It means if user sets IsPassword=true then I show the Eye button. By tapping this button, the password is shown or hidden.

The problem is here, when the focus is on the entry and user tap the Eye button, the focus gone from Entry because of tapping another element. When I call the focus method in tap event, the keyboard is flickiring.

So, I want to the entry does not lose the focus if I tap the 'Eye' button but if I tap somewhere else, it can behaves normal (as default).

I created renderers for ios and android and for android I added some code in the MainActivity to keep the focus but the problem is that, I need to somehow find out it focuses only when I tap the Eye button.

Here is android code

```
public class MainActivity : BaseActivity
  {
    private bool _lieAboutCurrentFocus;

    public override Android.Views.View CurrentFocus => _lieAboutCurrentFocus
                                                     ? null
                                                     : base.CurrentFocus;

    public override bool DispatchTouchEvent( MotionEvent ev )
    {
      try
      {
        if( this.CurrentFocus?.Parent is ConstantlyVisibleKeyboardEntry_DroidRenderer cer
         && cer.Element is ConstantlyVisibleKeyboardEntry )
        {
          _lieAboutCurrentFocus = true;
        }

        var result = base.DispatchTouchEvent( ev );
        _lieAboutCurrentFocus = false;
        return result;
      }
      catch( System.Exception ex )
      {
        ex.HandleException( 502773 );
      }

      return true;
    }
```

DispatchTouchEvent is triggered before Tap Event. So I cannot understand if user tapped the Eye button in DispatchTouchEvent because the tap event of the button did not executed yet.

Comment: Android dispatch the touch event from the parent to the child. So you can't **make entry don't lose the focus if I tap the 'Eye' button but if I tap somewhere else, it can behaves normal (as default)**. You can just make it keep focused unless user presses the back button.